# How to format datetime to be shown in EST or PST

Tags: mysql

`select created_at from foos;`

Shows the output in UTC format. How should I format this to be shown for EST or PST?

```
2015-03-05 00:00:25
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CONVERT_TZ` function to do it.

`CONVERT_TZ()` converts a datetime value dt from the time zone given by from_tz to the time zone given by to_tz and returns the resulting value.

```
UPDATE foos 
SET created_at = CONVERT_TZ('dt', 'to_tz', 'from_tz' )

UPDATE foos 
SET created_at = CONVERT_TZ('created_at', 'EST', 'UTC' );
```

For Ex:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2004-01-01 12:00:00','GMT','MET');
```

In your case:

```
UPDATE foos 
SET created_at = CONVERT_TZ('2015-03-05 00:00:25', 'EST', 'UTC' );
```

Here you can find documentation for the same:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz